# Where is my TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, wpf-controls

I'm trying - as a complete WPF noob - to create a hierarchical data bound 'TreeView', using the `HumanResources.Emplpoyee` table of the AdventureWorks DB, via EF 5 Code First. After following some examples, I've come up with the following, which produces a totally blank `MainWindow` when run.

```
<Window x:Class="FlatTree.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:AdventureWorks.Models;assembly=AdventureWorks"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subordinates}" DataType="{x:Type models:Employee}">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Title}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var ctx = new AdventureWorksContext();
        Employees = TreeBuilder.BuildEmployeeTree(ctx.Employees);
    }
}
```

`BuildEmployeeTree` works, and turns the list of Employee entities, with their `ManagerId` and `Subordinates` (renamed from `Employee1`) properties, into a tree model, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Employee> BuildEmployeeTree(IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
    var flatTree = employees.ToList();
    foreach (var emp in employees)
    {
        if (emp.ManagerID != null)
        {
            var manager = flatTree.Single(e => e.EmployeeID == emp.ManagerID);
            manager.Subordinates.Add(emp);
        }
    }
    return flatTree;
}
```

What am I not doing, or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set the `DataContext` of your `Window`, you can set it in constructor after initializations

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var ctx = new AdventureWorksContext();
    Employees = TreeBuilder.BuildEmployeeTree(ctx.Employees);
    DataContext = this;
}
```